# Landsat 8 bands of 432 looks too dark in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, landsat, landsat-8, band

I have created a composite map using the combination of Landsat 8 bands of 4, 3 and 2 (I read this combination gives true natural color) to see the scene in true color in ArcGIS, but it looks too dark. I couldn't see things clearly from this map.
[image: What I have got as a composite of the band 4, 3 and 2]

but I wanted to create this kind of composite map, which is easy to recognise the forest, river etc. How to create this kind of map?

[image: I want to create this kind of composite map]

What is wrong with it?

Comment: This problem is due to the clouds in the image. If you change the settings to read from the min/max from the extent not from the whole image you can get better results.

Comment: Try a (Band 6 - Shortwave Infrared), (Band 5 - Near Infrared), (Band 3 - Green) combination.. It'll brighten things up